# How to redirect with error message in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Routes

```
const router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/sayhello',(req,res) => {
    res.render('index',{data:"hello WOrld"});
    //if a redirect method is called in this function then we should get a message with redirect 
});

router.get('/sayhelloandhi',(req,res) => {
    res.redirect('/');
    //How to pass a message with redirect method  
});
```

How to pass a message to redirect method in express.js ?

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass data with `res.redirect()` but you can pass your data with queries or params for example :

```
router.get('/sayhelloandhi',(req,res) => {
     res.redirect('/?data=error');  
});

router.get('/',(req,res) => {
     let {data} = req.query;
     res.render('index', {data})
});
```

and with params :

```
router.get('/sayhelloandhi',(req,res) => {
     res.redirect('/error');  
});

router.get('/:data',(req,res) => {
     let {data} = req.params;
     res.render('index', {data})
});
```